# Bitmap Memory leak - Android

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm having a memory leak in my app which is triggering GC a number of times and causing performance issues. I generated a `leak suspect report` using `MAT`. Here is the report:

**Problem Suspect 1:**
*One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "" occupies 4,194,368 (20.13%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "".*

**Problem Suspect 2:**
*The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "", occupies 3,962,504 (19.02%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".*

**Problem Suspect 3:**
*One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "" occupies 3,145,792 (15.10%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "".*

Judging from the reports its obvious that memory leak is because of bitmap. I've researched a lot but couldn't rectify this leak. Please help me out. I'm using  `ImageLoader` class to download and display bitmaps. To use this class I simply call the `displayImage()` method. Here is the code:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    private static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private int maxNoOfConnections = 4;
    FileCache fileCache;
    ExecutorService executorService;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;
    PhotosLoader photosLoader;
    Handler handler;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    private ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxNoOfConnections);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    public static ImageLoader getInstance(Context context) {
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        return imageLoader;
    }

    public void displayImage(String url, ProgressBar pBar, ImageView imageView) {
        photosLoader = new PhotosLoader(url, imageView, pBar);
        executorService.submit(photosLoader);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        if (bitmap != null)
            return bitmap;

        try
        {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("inNews", "Image Url Malformed");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        String url;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar pBar;
        Bitmap bmp;

        public PhotosLoader(String url, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar pBar) {
            this.url = url;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.pBar = pBar;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            bmp = getBitmap(url);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (bmp != null)
                    {
                        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    } else
                    {
                        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_no_image_grid);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me rectify my code. Thanks!

**Note:** I've not used `bitmap.recycle()` since, the documentation says that post-Honeycomb the GC collects bitmaps and its no longer necessary to forcefully recycle it !

Comment: You receive the memory leak at a random time, always at the same time, when you rotate the device...?

Comment: You should read about SoftReference in Android doc, in your case if you store the returned Bitmap somewhere, It will remain in memory

Comment: @Fustigador whenever I do any action that involves loading images. Not specifically rotating the device.

Comment: @PlumillonForge I don't want to store references. I'm already running short of memory ! :)

Comment: Yeah this is the goal of SoftReference : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html when you run out of memory, Android will automatically flush ressource pointed by the SoftReference, I ran into a similar problem (Bitmap causing OOM) and the SoftReference solved it

Comment: @gauravsapiens I got 5 leak of images. How can I solve that . I hope you succsess that so please  suggest me.                      27 instances of "android.graphics.Bitmap", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 2,977,016 (24.40%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x4122a3e8 - 1,048,640 (8.60%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41256058 - 635,856 (5.21%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41aeda78 - 326,104 (2.67%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x4187fb90 - 157,504 (1.29%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41a1a4e8 - 144,064 (1.18%) bytes.

Comment: @gauravsapiens I also got three suspect leakage error. How can I solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak problem always Java's problems.
I understand your code, code simple imagecache tool. Check SampleSize value and executor service run on only one thread. Four Thread have big memory and this background thread action. Your "handler" exchange to "runOnUIThread"

You should use;

Activity **activity** = (Activity)imageView.getContext();

```
__activity__.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
{
 if (bmp != null)
                    {
                        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    } else
                    {
                        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_no_image_grid);
                    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't help rather it might unnecesarily keep reference to `Activity`.

Comment: I use imagecache same as your code but I don't get any memory leak error. I sent my code 2-3 hours later if you want it. You give me communication link such as "email" I will sent java file group.(package)

Comment: Yes sure, my mail id is g.arora217@gmail.com. Thanks ! :)

Comment: @nurisezgin Hello I got getting so many memory leak. Could you please send me the code to my email mmaidul.islam@gmail.com . Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe, you will use google volley library "git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley" or use BitmapFactory.Options ==> inSampleSize attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Singleton instance... I made a fork of the LazyList project, check this:

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/LazyList

I have the same Memory Leak but, and maybe I am wrong, this singleton will never be garbage collected unless you kill the process with System.exit().

That is why the original LazyList project not use Singleton. I also think that if you need a cache you will need to be fast and the same for all the application.

The important thing in this ImageLoader is the FileCache and MemoryCache, when you call clearCache the bitmaps where collected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simple, just keep clearing cache when you dont need memory/when OOM exception arises. I did that for you

```
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have to initialise a library in an activity, always pass the application context, not the activity context.